# How to solve this quartic congruence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given $x^4 + 36x^3 - 19x^2 + 11x - 14 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$. How would one go about solving such an congruence equation? Maybe it's possible to reduce this to a quadratic congruence? I can't figure it out! Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is equivalent to $$x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1\equiv 0\pmod{5}$$ since $36\equiv -19\equiv 11\equiv -14\equiv1\pmod{5}$
You can test all the numbers $0,1,2,3,4$ and see that the only one that fits is $1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you maybe point out how -19 can be seen to be congruent 1 mod 5? I see that it's just consecutively adding fives to -19, but what's the formal background? I'm still a little confused when it comes to negative integers in modular arithmetic, after all there're no "negative congruence classes", so they have to end up in 0,1,...,p-1

Comment: No problem,well you have that $-19=-20+1$ which means that it's equivalent to $1$ since $20$ is a multiply of 5 other then that you have that $-19\equiv -4\pmod{5}$.We can add 5 since it's equivalent to adding a zero hence adding $5$ we get that $-4\equiv 5-4\equiv 1\pmod{5}$

Comment: I see. Thanks again.

Comment: @jazz You can eliminate the brute-force checking by using little Fermat, obtaining a much more general result - see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ p\!:\ f \equiv x^{p-1}\!+\,\cdots+\!x^2\!+\!x\!+\!1\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, (x\!-\!1)f \equiv \color{#c00}{x^p}\!-1\equiv \color{#c00}x\!-\!1\equiv 0\ $ by $\,\rm\color{#c00}{little\ Fermat}$.

Comment: Thanks, Bill. This is really quite neat. From this it's obvious that $x = 1$ is the only solution.

Comment: @Number Any chance you can do that again using this equation instead? $x^4 + 21x^3 + 5x^2 + 7x + 1 \equiv 0 \mod 23$ I know the answer is `x=18 | x=19` but I don't know the steps involved nor do I get how you're only using `1`s in your answer when the OP had integers > 1. I suspect it has something to do with their example, so I'm hoping the theorem applied to my  example will shed some light since the solution to my equation is not 1.